# SQL Server : how to use select top (@number) syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a SQL Server `employee` table as follows:

```
No   empno
-----------
1    NULL
2    7889
3    7778
4    6454
5    7777
```

I want to select row 3

```
SET @count = 3 

SELECT TOP (@count) empno 
FROM employee 
EXCEPT 
SELECT TOP (@count-1) empno 
FROM employee
```

I get an error at `@count`:

> Must declare the scalar variable @count

How can I fix this statement?

By the way, I use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and they don't have `SELECT ROW`?

Comment: Oh, my bad, thank you for answering. Is there anyway to select a single row from that table?

Comment: Sorry is this what you mean??
DECLARE @count =3
SELECT TOP (@count) *? FROM employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your variables first

```
DECLARE @count int
SET @count = 3 
SELECT TOP (@count) empno FROM employee EXCEPT 
SELECT TOP (@count-1) empno FROM employee
```

or you can use `Row_number()` to select a single row

Look here it will help you do that

http://www.advancesharp.com/questions/18687/select-nth-row-from-a-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

It is not so beautiful as EXCEPT, but it reads table only once:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 3

SELECT  TOP 1 * FROM (
    SELECT  TOP (@count) * FROM employee ORDER BY empno
) as t ORDER BY empno Desc
```